# Display number sequence based on the number of data in database

Tags: php, numbers, sequence

[image]

How can I display the number based on the number of data from database.

For example, the above picture, shows data extract from the database. In my database there are two data. Therefore I would like to display number 1 and 2 at the No column.

And if there is four data in the database, I would like to display number 1, 2, 3 and 4 at the No column.

Coding to display the above table

```
<?php
$sql= mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM employee INNER JOIN cash ON employee.emp_id = cash.emp_id WHERE cash_status='Pending'");
echo "<table id='dataTable' width='850' border='1' align='center'>";

echo "<tr>
        <th height='50'>No</th>
        <th height='50'>Employee Number</th>
        <th height='50'>Name</th>
        <th height='50'>Department</th>
        <th height='50'>Date Apply</th>
        <th height='50'>Date Cash To Be Use</th>
        <th height='50'>Amount</th>
        <th height='50'>Status</th>
        <th height='50'>Cash Id</th>
        <th height='50'>View</th>
    </tr>";


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'></td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['emp_id']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['emp_name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['emp_department']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['cash_dapply']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['cash_duse']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>RM" .$row['cash_amount']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['cash_status']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['cash_id']. "</td>";
        echo"<td height='30'><a href= cadvance_approval.php?id=".$row['emp_id']."&cash_id=".$row['cash_id']."><img src='../img/view_user.png' width='20' height='20'></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";    
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code that prints this table?

Comment: As far I can tell, the **No** column has no values there...

Comment: it's simple you can take `$counter` and achieve this

Comment: @Halcyon the coding has been updated. There's no code under the No column yet as I don't know how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the Below Code :

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$sql= mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM employee INNER JOIN cash ON employee.emp_id = cash.emp_id WHERE cash_status='Pending'");
echo "<table id='dataTable' width='850' border='1' align='center'>";

echo "<tr>
        <th height='50'>No</th>
        <th height='50'>Employee Number</th>
        <th height='50'>Name</th>
        <th height='50'>Department</th>
        <th height='50'>Date Apply</th>
        <th height='50'>Date Cash To Be Use</th>
        <th height='50'>Amount</th>
        <th height='50'>Status</th>
        <th height='50'>Cash Id</th>
        <th height='50'>View</th>
    </tr>";


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>".$++i."</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['emp_id']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['emp_name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['emp_department']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['cash_dapply']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['cash_duse']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>RM" .$row['cash_amount']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['cash_status']. "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' height='30'>" .$row['cash_id']. "</td>";
        echo"<td height='30'><a href= cadvance_approval.php?id=".$row['emp_id']."&cash_id=".$row['cash_id']."><img src='../img/view_user.png' width='20' height='20'></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";    
?>
```

Comment: Your _No_ column starts at `0`. Either do `$i = 1` or `++$i`.

Answer (score 0):

@Hardy Change .$++i. to .++$i.